# Spark and common partitionner : will two separate referentials partitioned by the same key only load their common partition at join time?

Tags: java, apache-spark, dataset, rdd, partitioning

French cities data (accounting, enterprises, jobs...) can be conveniently partitioned by department (`29=Finistère`, `33=Gironde`, etc...), and in my datasets this field is named `codeDepartement`.

I have many referentials of entreprises, accounting, taxation and so on for these cities, they are sorted by `codeCommune` within these departments partitions :
`enterprises = enterprises.repartition(col("codeDepartement")).sortWithinPartition("codeCommune")`

---

Then, comes the time where I want to join them for analysis :

- I have `local[12]` configuration for master.
- I want to study the cities of *Finistère*. It implies *Apache Spark* will load the `cities\cities_part_29` of the parquet file to create the internal RDD `cities_rdd_29`, or something like this, and I assume it does.

---

But when the join steps begin, even if join conditions are of the kind :
`enterprises.col("codeCommune") = cities.col("codeCommune")`
**is it enough** to ensure that *Spark* will *only create* the internal enterprise RDD `enterprises_rdd_29` from the `enterprises\enterprises_part_29` and won't attempt to search among other ones ?

1. Or isn't it enough and I should add for the join condition : `enterprises.col("codeDepartement") = cities.col("codeDepartement")` ?
2. Or, isn't it still enough, and I should have a more **explicit common partitionner** that will link these two datasets,
   and then, how such a partitionner is created for a *Dataset* ?
3. I'm misleading and I'm missing something else ?

Answer (score 0):

> will two separate referentials partitioned by the same key only load their common partition at join time?

Two dataframes partitioned by the join key will be loaded into the same partitions allowing for a local join. However, it looks like you have partitioned by a column other than the join column, so there will be a shuffle. To avoid this, repartition your input datasets by the join key before joining. e.g.

```
enterprises = enterprises.repartition(col("codeCommune"))
cities = cities.repartition(col("codeCommune"))
enterprises.join(cities, col("codeCommune"))
```

Comment: No, this would be a bad idea. It would lead to 35,000 partitions. Partition and join column are two differents things in my mind.

Comment: No need to fear many partitions, 35K is a small number in computing terms. https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/tuning.html#memory-usage-of-reduce-tasks recommends many small partitions and says that Spark is efficient down to tasks as short as 200ms. This is my experience also. For SortMergeJoin, dfs will be partitioned by join column by Spark anyway. You can avoid the shuffle by loading the dfs into partitions by join key directly from their source files.

Comment: No, I still disagree. First issue, is that it's more than a nightmare when saving this on a paquet file : 35000 cities = 35000 folders with a single file inside each of them : ten minutes et least, and few minutes for reading. It's counterproductive. Partitions aren't primary keys when primary keys are (quite) the unique identifier for the first dataset dataset, the key of two to five records in the second one, and only one hundred in the third one .

Comment: You can `coalesce` down to a smaller number of partitions before writing the final output. If the number of output partitions is >= number of nodes, then `coalesce` is inexpensive with no further shuffle.

Comment: I would have to repartition them by `codeDepartement` then, else it has definitvely no sense. No sorry. I think it's a wrong advice.